# lag when piping data from nodejs to play(sox)

Tags: node.js, pipe, playback, lag, sox

Recently I was super excited to discover [baudio](https://github.com/substack/baudio) but unfortunately it has a bug (issue #13) that renders it practically useless. In light of this I've taken the core ideas and started making my own version. here's a breakdown of what it does.

- generate amplitude output at short intervals in the form of 8bit pcm data (aka single hex characters representing amplitude levels 0-15)
- pipe node's sdtout to play's (sox's) stdin

I ~neeed~ it to be an instrument usable in real time so I'm piping the data (8bit amplitude samples) in chunks 20 times per second but this seems to cause a lot of lag and choppiness. when I create a file out of node's output and pipe the uninterrupted stream of hex digits to play:

`cat bitfile | play -c 1 -r 44100 -t s8 -`

it works perfectly.

[here](http://pastebin.com/yB8P2pZ7) is the js for my node applet. it requires the 'through' module:

`npm install through`

So my question is:

**can I do anything to reduce this piping lag? faster hardware? different approach? hopeless?**

Comment: I can't try this, but have you tried specifying the `highWatermark` of the streams you're using?